# How to prevent/prohibit the creation of SharePoint 2010 workflows (on-premises)?

Tags: 2010, workflow

Is there any way to prevent users from creating SP 2010 workflows (on-premises SPS 2013, 2016, 2019)?

Constraints:

- Want existing SP10WFs to continue to work.
- Want existing SP13WFs to continue to work.
- Want the ability to edit/delete existing SP10WFs.
- Want the ability to create/edit/delete SP13WFs.
- Want the ability to continue using SharePoint Designer.

Why?

[SP10WF is being retired in SPO](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepoint-2010-workflow-retirement-1ca3fff8-9985-410a-85aa-8120f626965f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) and need to stop proliferation of SP10WF in preparation for migration to M365.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following at the Web Application, Site Collection, or Web level (so substitute the cmdlets appropriately):

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication https://webAppUrl
$wa.AllowCreateDeclarativeWorkflow = $false
$wa.Update()
```

There are no settings to control creation, deletion, editing of 2013 workflows. The only option for 2013 is to remove the Workflow Manager binding from the farm, which will obviously prevent all 2013 workflow functionality from occurring.

Comment: thanks. I suspected as much (based on, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/set-spworkflowconfig?view=sharepoint-ps) but needed confirmation.